# Event Handler for a dynamically created control

Tags: c#, asp.net, events

I am dynamically creating an asp.net `RadioButton` and inserting it into my web page:

```
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
rb.ID  = "rb" + ReportPKey;
rb.Text = "ReportName";
phUiControls.Controls.Add(rb);
```

I have the following method:

```
protected void rb_CheckedChanged( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    // stuff
}
```

How do I wire this up so that `rb_CheckedChanged` is fired when `rb` is clicked?

Comment: rb.CheckedChanged += rb_CheckedChanged

Comment: Also remember that you will need to recreate this control state in your `Init` method on postback, otherwise the event will not be invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
rb.CheckedChanged += rb_CheckedChanged
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it with an anonymous delegate (clean for these types of scenarios):

```
var rb = new RadioButton{ ID = "rb" + ReportPKey, Text = "ReportName" };
phUiControls.Controls.Add( rb );

rb.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) => {
    // event handler code
};
```

Or (as several other people have pointed out):

```
rb.CheckedChanged += rb_CheckedChanged
```

In context of the page lifecycle:

```
protected override OnInit( EventArgs e ){
    BuildDynamicControls();
    base.OnInit( e );
}

private void BuildDynamicControls(){
    var rb = new RadioButton{ ID = "rb" + ReportPKey, Text = "ReportName" };
    phUiControls.Controls.Add( rb );

    rb.CheckedChanged += (sender, e) => {
        // event handler code
    };
}
```

Comment: If you use an anonymous delegate how will you wire it up again on postback?

Comment: Dynamic controls need to be recreated with every page execution; you would simply wire up the event after creating the dynamic control.

Answer (score 0):

```
RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
rb.ID  = "rb"+ReportPKey;
rb.Text = ReportName  ;
rb.CheckedChanged += rb_CheckedChanged
phUiControls.Controls.Add(rb);
```