# Linking "DataBindingComplete" event handler with custom input

Tags: c#, datagridview, lambda, event-handling

I'm working in a Windows Forms project where I have to dynamically create DataGridViews, populate them with one DataTable and then format the cells based on another DataTable.  The code is something like this:

```
my_forms_function(){
  DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
  DataTable values = get_values();
  DataTable formatting = get_formatting();
  dgv.DataSource = values;
  format_grid(dgv, formatting);
  WindowsForm.Add(dgv);
}
```

My problem is that the format_grid method gets called before the DataGridView is fully configured after binding the DataSource, so I can't refer to individual cells during formatting like I need to.  So I need to link the format_grid method (or its functionality) to the DataBindingComplete event.  I've been searching around and found stuff like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6457474/c-sharp-eventhandler-with-custom-arguments) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10657470/event-handler-for-a-dynamically-created-control).

Lambda statements seem to be the way to go, but I haven't been able to make it work.  There's always some kind of syntax error which prevents me from compiling.  Can anyone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are on track, it's just a matter of getting the syntax correct.  Try:

```
dgv.DataBindingComplete += (sender, e) => format_grid(dgv, formatting);
```

I don't have a full example to duplicate your code, but with the following simplistic example, it works:

```
string hello = "Hello World!";
DataTable values = GetValues();
dataGridView1.DataSource = values;
dataGridView1.DataBindingComplete += (sender, e) => this.DoStuff(hello);

private void DoStuff(string text)
{
  Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Comment: Didn't work for me at first, but I finally realized why.  The method that I'm working in ('my_forms_function()') is ALSO an event-triggered method.  So 'sender' and 'e' were both already defined in the method, which is why I was getting a syntax error.  So I changed the names of "sender" and "e" in the parent method and was then able to use the lambda statement as you suggested.  Works perfectly! :)